# has_object_permission is not called for custom defined API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset SampleViewSet for API `POST` `/api/samples/sample_id/check`.  I have defined object level permission for it.

```
class SamplePermission(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return True

class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (SamplePermission, )

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def check(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            print "check"
```

The function has_object_permission is not getting called when I call the API `POST` `/api/samples/check`.  What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Permission is not work because a method `check_object_permissions` calls in `get_object` function. So you should call one of that functions in your `check` function:

```
    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def check(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = self.get_object()
        ....
```

Or you could add permissions directly in `detail_route`

```
    @detail_route(
    permission_classes=[SamplePermission],
    methods=['post'])
    def check(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

Comment: Edited the question as per your comment.  The function gets called for GET api.  It doesn't work for any custom-defined API.

Comment: I added permissions directly in detail_route.  I have both has_permission and has_object_permission definined inside Sample Permission.  'has_permission' gets called whereas 'has_object_permission' is not called.

Comment: @linuxfreak so you should write all your permissions code in a question. But I guess your first permission work and restrict other object permission. Here the text from docs **Note: The instance-level has_object_permission method will only be called if the view-level has_permission checks have already passed. Also note that in order for the instance-level checks to run, the view code should explicitly call .check_object_permissions(request, obj). If you are using the generic views then this will be handled for you by default.**